# How do you configure Kestrel to use a random dynamic port from a defined range of ports

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there any way to configure Kestrel to use a random port from a defined range ( for example from 5500 to 5600)?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost() =>

        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:0") // port zero to use random dynamic port but doesn't respoect the range port
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: why do you want a random port?

Comment: Actually it's for multi-instance servers, I need to set a port range and each server will choose a random port from that range

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we are currently support a ranged dynamic port, checked [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#port-0)  , not saying it is a ranged port

I raised a github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24903) and you can subscribe that to see if this would be a new feature in the future